# Finding underlying group given a set of characters

Tags: finite-groups, characters

I have 2 questions but I am not sure if they are reasonable:

1) Given a finite set of characters $\chi$, is it always possible to find a finite group that has $\chi$ as its set of irreducible characters? Intuitively I feel this is not true, but I am not sure how to approach proving this.

2) Given a set of irreducible characters, and the knowledge that they are generated by a group, how could one go about finding the underlying group?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What does it mean to be given a character abstractly?  Do you mean to say that you have a fixed finite set $S$  and that you are given a collection of functions from that set to $\mathbb C$ and you ask whether we can find a group structure on $S$ for which the collection constitutes all of the characters?

Comment: @lulu Yes, this is almost exactly what I mean, with the exception being that the collection of functions is the set of irreducible characters over the group and not the set of all characters of the group.

Do you think the question is unclear in this respect?

Comment: For almost all such sets of maps there will be no group. And even if there is one, it will not be determined by its set of characters.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I understand what you mean by the first part ogf your statement, in that it would not form a homomorphism structure (in the abelian group case) with high likelihood. I do not understand how you concluded the second part of your statement

Comment: Yes, I think the question is unclear.  As stated, with my interpretation, it is obvious that most collections can't come from group structures.  For example, if the size of $S$ is $p$, a prime, then you need all of your functions to take values in the $p^{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: For one thing all the values would have to be algebraic integers. There would have to be an element for which they are all natural numbers. And so on...

Comment: @lulu could you please comment on the second part of the question

Comment: The second part comes from there being examples of non-isomorphic groups with the same set of characters.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoftm the second part does not imply that a group cannot be found, it is just not unique

Comment: Well, it sounds technical but maybe not impossible.  I'd try to do it for cyclic groups first.  Try to identify a generator.  Is this arising in some context?

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the delayed response. I was looking at a problem that involved finding classes of matrices that are diagonalized by a particular given matrix and finding characters that matched the elements of the matrix would allow one to do so (ref. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02689.pdf). But to do this, the characters should be generated by a group, which as mentioned would not be possible in most cases